# Retryable pattern for file processing in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to process a large file (with columns and same format lines). Since I need to consider the cases that the program crashes during the processing, I need this processing program to be  retryable, which means after it crashes and I start the program again, it can continue to process the file starting with the line it failed.

Is there any pattern I can follow or library I can use? Thank you!

---

Update:

About the crashing cases, it is not just about OOM or some internal issues. It also could be caused by the timeout with other parts or machine crashing. So try/catch can't handle this.

---

Another update:

About the chunking the file, it is feasible in my case but not that as simple as it sounds. As I said, the file is formatted with several columns and I can split it up into hundreds of files based on one of the column and then process the files one by one. But instead of doing this, I would like to learn more about the common solution about processing big file/data supporting retrying.

Comment: tried chunking the data?

Comment: Why not put the line handling logic in a try/catch block?

Comment: Would the retryer by @jbnizet [link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=490) together with this  [link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines(java.io.File, java.nio.charset.Charset, com.google.common.io.LineProcessor)
  work for you?

Comment: Please see my update in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain a checkpoint/commit style logic in your code. So when the program runs again it starts from the same checkpoint.

You can use RandomAccessFile to read the file and use the getFilePointer() as your checkpoint which you preserver. When you execute the program again you start with this checkpoint by calling seek(offset).

Comment: Any good idea about how to implement the "maintain a checkpoint/commit style logic"?

Comment: Depending upon what kind file and what you doing it may differ. But I would read line by line and only after a line is processed store the file pointer. If you have database available then store the pointer there or in some file.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it (though am not a pro)

1. Create a [LineProcessor](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LineProcessor.html) called on every line in file

   class Processor implements LineProcessor> {

   ```
           private List<String> lines = Lists.newLinkedList();
           private int startFrom = 0;
           private int lineNumber = 0;

           public Processor(int startFrom) {
               this.startFrom = startFrom;
           }

           @Override
           public List<String> getResult() {
               return lines;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean processLine(String arg0) throws IOException {
               lineNumber++;
               if (lineNumber < startFrom) {
                   // do nothing
               } else {
                   if (new Random().nextInt() % 50000 == 0) {
                       throw new IOException("Randomly thrown Exception " + lineNumber);
                   }
                    //Do the hardwork here
                   lines.add(arg0);
                   startFrom++;
               }
               return true;
           }
       }
   ```
2. Create a [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) for Reading Files that makes use of my [LineProcessor](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LineProcessor.html)

   ```
   class Reader implements Callable<List<String>> {

       private int startFrom;

       public Reader(int startFrom) {
           this.startFrom = startFrom;
       }

       @Override
       public List<String> call() throws Exception {
           return Files.readLines(new File("/etc/dictionaries-common/words"),
               Charsets.UTF_8, new Processor(startFrom));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Wrap the [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) in a Retryer and call it using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
   BasicConfigurator.configure();

   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

   Future<List<String>> lines = executor.submit(RetryerBuilder
           .<List<String>> newBuilder()
           .retryIfExceptionOfType(IOException.class)
           .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.stopAfterAttempt(100)).build()
           .wrap(new Reader(100)));

   logger.debug(lines.get().size());
   executor.shutdown();
   logger.debug("Happily Ever After");
   ```

   }

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample code. There is a problem with the code, which is that it can't handle the other kind of crashing like OS crashed or power out. So I think it is required to persist the pointer into a file or something.

Comment: @Xiezi  All you need is a way of saving the start value. In my Example I used 100 (new Reader(100)).   Save it to a file and read it from there when restarting

Answer (score 0):

Try catch won's save from OOM error. You should process the file in chunks and store the location after every successfull chunck into filesystem/database/what ever place where it remains persistent even if your program crashes. Then you can read the previous point from the place you stored it when you restart your software. You must also cleanup this information when the whole file is processed.